# How to ignore config files in SVN?

Tags: svn

What is the proper syntax to ignore a specific file such as a configuration file which may be different depending if it is running on Development, QA or Production?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App.config only for my developer machine.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309178/app-config-only-for-my-developer-machine)

Comment: Put your config files in a different svn tree, that you can branch into dev, QA and production versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and check in a template `web.config.template` and ignore `web.config` the 'deployed' version.

To automate the `web.config.template` customization create a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

you can add property svn:ignore in your repository and ignore *.config files or exactly web.config

Comment: That doesn't help, `svn:ignore` only works to hide files that svn would otherwise add