# How to ignore modified files under some directory when executing 'svn status', but still get them updated when executing 'svn update'?

Tags: svn

I have some personalized files locally, which are not need to commit.

They mess up the result of executing *svn status*, so I want to hide them from the result of *svn status*.

But I still want them updated when executing *svn update*.

Is there any way to achieve this in Subversion?

I do not care about possible conflict and will fix them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way to have a versioned file but to ignore it on `svn status`/`svn commit`.

The best practice for such situation is to have versioned template of the file, and make a copy of it for every working copy, then modify a copy as mush as you like:

```
Versioned file:    config.txt.orig
Unversioned file:  config.txt
```

You can also add the unversioned file (`config.txt`) to `svn:ignore`, so it will not show up in the `svn status`.

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

---

There is also a non-standard solution in the case you are using TortoiseSVN client -- special `ignore-on-commit` changelist:

- http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html#tsvn-dug-commit-ignore

---

More resources:

- http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit
- [svn ignore a file but include it in checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139882/svn-ignore-a-file-but-include-it-in-checkout)
- [How to ignore config files in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833668/how-to-ignore-config-files-in-svn)
- [SVN: Is there a way to mark a file as "do not commit"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635446/svn-is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-file-as-do-not-commit/635787#635787)