# VS config file and Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have checked-out a C# project held in a SVN repository and the .config file (in the bin/debug and/or bin/release folder) contains a path to a log file.  I need to change that path to run it locally, but I don't want to submit my change to the repository as it will then be wrong for the live environment.

If I set it to ignore this file, then anybody else checking-out will not have this file at all.

The back-end is using Microsoft's VisualSVN running on Windows Server 2012 R2

What are my options? and how to do them?

Comment: https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore modified files under some directory when executing 'svn status', but still get them updated when executing 'svn update'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753758/how-to-ignore-modified-files-under-some-directory-when-executing-svn-status-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set those files to `ignore-on-commit` [ChangeLists](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html).

In your commit dialog, right click your file(s) and select `Move to change list > ignore-on-commit`.

[image]

As Tortoise [documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html) says:

> Changelists are purely a local client feature. Creating and removing
>   changelists will not affect the repository, nor anyone else's working
>   copy. They are simply a convenient way for you to organise your files.

Comment: So, to stop everybody else from commiting their local copy, they have to do the same.  Not ideal, but this is better than nothing

Comment: @Graham Only you know your exact needs but I think the ideal solution is doing what everyone else does: commit templates, not actual settings files.